# Cannot Airplay to a Mac; the option doesn't show up

Tags: macos, monterey, airplay

I have an iPhone and an iPad with IOS 17, and I am trying to stream Airplay from either of them to a couple of Macs.

The first of them is a MacBook Air from 2015 running macOS 12.7.1 (the newest version it supports). According to [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/es-es/guide/mac-help/mchleee00ec8/12.0/mac/12.0), you are supposed to go to **System Preferences > Sharing** and click on **Airplay receiver** on the left... but I don't see that option at all. What I see instead is this:

[image: Screenshot of the Sharing preferences window]

I have tried logging into iCloud on my Mac (which I don't usually do), but it doesn't work either.

According to [Apple's own documentation](https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT204689), "Airplay works better" with macOS versions later than mine, but it also says that it should still work with older versions.

(The same thing happens with the other Mac, except that it has an even older version (macOS 10.14, I think), so I guess that one is easier to explain. But I still wonder why I don't have that Airplay option in my macOS 12 MacBook).